# Scala play implicit path binder for two path variables

Tags: scala, rest, playframework

I want to write implicit `PathBinder` for this url `/repo/:owner/:name` and I my controller should be like this:

```
case class GitHubRepositoryId(owner: String, name: String)
def get(repoId: GitHubRepositoryId) = {}
```

Is it possible to write one ? From [play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders) I cannot find solution for that. Only `QueryStringBindable` can access multiple variables from URL and construct POJO from those.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your route to `GET /repo/*repoId controllers.Controller.get(repoId: GitHubRespositoryId)`

Then define the PathBindable so that it manually parses out the `/` between owner and name. Something like this:

```
implicit val pathBinder = new PathBindable[GitHubRepositoryId] {
  override def bind(key: String, value: String): Either[String, GitHubRepositoryId] = {
    val parts = value.split('/')
    if (parts.size != 2) {
      Left("Not found")
    } else {
      Right(GitHubRepositoryId(parts(0), parts(1)))
    }
  }

  override def unbind(key: String, repoId: GitHubRepositoryId): String = {
    s"${repoId.owner}/${repoId.name}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this solution still works if i would have url like `/repo/*repoId/comments` ?

Comment: Yes, it does for me in play 2.3